# how to give different videos in background of <div> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dealing with a website such that it contains different videos in the  background of site. I want this approach by using `<div>` tag and for that I tried the following...

```
<video id="bgvid" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" style="margin-right: 3px;width: 300px;">
  <source src="vid/le'toile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="polina">
  <h1>Le'toile</h1>
  <p>ART of Switching</p>
  <p>We believe that a seamless blend of Art & Technology makes what we create, Alive and Evolving.</p>      
</div>
```

It displays the video in the background but when we try above code again to display another video at background then it overlays with 1st video. Means only the 2nd video plays. So, how to play both videos using 2 `<div>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
<video loop autoplay muted poster="path/to/screenshot.jpg">
    <source src="path/to/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="path/to/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Please check this link:-https://html5backgroundvideos.com/how-to-create-a-html5-background-video-using-html-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple video tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

</body>

</html>
```

It wont overlap

Answer (score 0):

In your code set the autoplay attribute to "autoplay" explicitly and it will play the video

```
<video id="bgvid" playsinline="" autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="" style="margin-right: 3px;width: 300px;">
<source src="vid/le'toile.mp4"></video>
<div id="polina"><h1>Le'toile</h1><p>ART of Switching<p>We believe that a seamless blend of Art & Technology makes what we create, Alive and Evolving.</p>
```

Hope this helps.